# Including dynamic script in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a script in a JS. Below is my code,

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<script async data-cfasync="false" src=""></script>';
```

I am getting below error when this JS code runs,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: your src tag is empty.

Comment: @tstoev: I have emptied the tag to hide the link.